How to save Excel file into SQL Server from the Web API?
I have a web server which returns an Excel file through its API. I'm retrieving this data from the SQL Server like this:
DECLARE @Object AS INT;
DECLARE @ResponseText AS VARCHAR(8000);

DECLARE @Body AS VARCHAR(8000) = 
'{
"StartDt": "2024-08-01",
"EndDt":"2024-08-02"
}'

EXEC sp_OACreate 'MSXML2.XMLHTTP', @Object OUT;
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'open', NULL, 'post','http://10.116.34.8:8129/runreport/ad17bc11-67ea-4f3e-b210-333e78ec9e9c', 'false'

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'setRequestHeader', null, 'Content-Type', 'application/json'
EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'send', null, @body

EXEC sp_OAMethod @Object, 'responseText', @ResponseText OUTPUT

How to save this @ResponseText into Excel file to read then again in SQL Server? I need to import then data in DB tables in a readable not varbinary format

Please use some external program, or at least SQL CLR to do this instead.

sp_OA stopped being the way to do this nearly 20 years ago.

First you need to create stream object, then you... just kidding, enough with SP_OA questions on how to replace a webservice with some shoddy sql code. A python or shudder powershell script can do this for you in less rows than the above script

You can use SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS) for such task.

Additionally to the above mentioned points: If your API really returns an Excel File, you probalby won't be able to store this BINARY data into a VARCHAR ....

Why do you not want it in a varbinary format? Excel files are binary. Why wouldn't you do this externally in Python or PowerShell, etc., instead of using the sp_OA* methods to leak resources everywhere and compromise the stability of your SQL Server instance?

Thank you! I don want to use any additional software to not complicate the task. Web API and SQL Sever are in the secure closed subnet. There is no need to think about security. If there is a another actual instrument inside of SQL Server please suggest. If a replace the type of @ResponseText with varbinary format will I be able to read the data from it in a human-readable format to fill my DB tables?

Powershell is usually installed on most sql server servers, unless you're doing your software in 1997s enclosures
